# Impossible to print a long long integer in C

Tags: c, printf, long-long

I know there are many topics on this subject but none of them helped me to fix my problem.
I work on Code::Blocks (with the option -std=c99 in "Properties>Project Build Options>Compiler Settings>Other Options") and the following code doesn't give the expected output:

```
long long val=1<<33;
printf("value: %llu",val);
```

In fact I obtain "value: 0" in the terminal.
How can I fix that problem?

When I write 30 instead of 33 (so val is an integer), I get the rigth answer. I have also tried %lld but that does not help.

Comment: Didn't your compiler warn about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't qualified the literals 1 and 33 in any way, `1<<33` will have an `int` as its type. If `int` is 32 bit (very common on compilers targeting 64 bit) then this expression will yield *undefined behaviour*.

A simple fix would be to write `1LL << 33`. `1LL` is a `long long`, and 33 will be promoted to that type too. The C++ standard guarantees that `long long` is *at least* 64 bits.

In many ways though I prefer `static_cast<std::int64_t>(1) << 33`.

Comment: The operands of `<<` and `>>` don't undergo usual arithmetic conversions. Having 33 promoted to `long long` in `1LL << 33` is a K&R C thing (the fact that K&R C didn't have `long long` aside).

Answer (score 3):

`1<<33` will invoke undefined behavior for 32 bit `int`.

#### C11: 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators:

> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1` `×` `2`<sup>`E2`</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. **If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` `×` `2`<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

Answer (score 1):

The shift `1<<33` is not done on a `long long` type. The `1` is an `int` here; cast it to `long long` or suffix it with `LL`, e.g., `1LL << 33`.